# Open editor for XML file depending on its content in Visual Studio

Tags: xml, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In my Visual Studio project I have an XML file containing an Excel workbook in **Excel Spreadsheet 2003 XML** format. Unfortunately the file extension is `.xml`.

Now I want to open this file by double-clicking it (from within Visual Studio) with Excel. But XML files are opened in the VS XML editor of course. If I change the association for XML files then XML files are also opened (or at least tried to open) by Excel, which is obviously not a good idea.

I also tried to *Open with...* the **Automatic editor selector (XML)** and the **Office XML Handler** but still no senseful results.

**So my question is:** How can I open an XML file containing the **Excel Spreadsheet 2003 XML** format with Excel, and any other XML file with the internal Visual Studio XML editor?

Comment: is it possible to change the extension? From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#XML_Spreadsheet): Though the intended file extension for this format is .xml, the program also correctly handles XML files with .xls extension

Comment: That's one possibility, but I'd like to avoid that. When opening a file like this one will get a modal dialog stating that the format and the extension do not match but could be opened any way.

Comment: As windows relies on extensions (and mime types if through browser), you would have to intercept the open with your own program that can check the header and launch the appropriate program.

Comment: I thought so. But how? Do I need to write a VS extension for this?